# Do I need to require original file when overriding controller from Rails Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I'm trying to override an action in a controller defined by a Rails Engine.

It seems like I need to require the original file before reopening the class, like so:

```
require File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'vendor/plugins/myplugin/app/controllers/some_controller')
class SomeController

  def index
    render :text => 'this is my index'
  end
end
```

This makes sense, but that require is pretty ugly.  Is there some sort of Rails magic that would allow me to avoid the initial require?

Comment: You can make it automatically by changing `ActiveSupport#require_or_load`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045068/extending-controllers-of-a-rails-3-engine-in-the-main-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complete guess...

Seems more of a load timing problem. As in, your file is getting loaded before the plug-in. Where is your action located? config/initializers? lib?

I'm not to sure when Rails Engines gets loaded so play around with the location (should work by putting it in lib).

Or, better yet, create your own plug-in with the changes and make sure it loads after the original.

And you probably want something more like:

```
SomeController.class_eval do

  def index
    ...
  end

end
```